# how to merge/update 2 identical SQL tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 SQL tables with the same structure. One is an updated version of the second.   How can I merge the 2 so that the newer table's records take precedence over the other, and records that do not have updates in the newer table are still included?

Original Table ID (is primary key):

```
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
11   AL    1 main street
22   BOB   2 main street
33   CHAZ  3 main street
```

Updated Table

```
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
11  AL     99 maple street
22  BOB    2 main street
```

Result I want

```
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
11    AL   99 maple street
22    BOB  2 main street
33    CHAZ 3 main street
```

thanks, 
MC

Answer (score 5):

`coalesce` will return the first non-null value. Combined with a `left join` this will first use the new data and if null the old one.

```
select coalesce(u.id, o.id) as id,
       coalesce(u.name, o.name) as name,
       coalesce(u.address, o.address) as address
from original_table o
left join updated_table u on u.id = o.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE o
SET Name=u.Name
    ,Address=u.Address
from [original] o
inner join [updated] u on u.id = o.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try union:

```
Select id as uid, name, address from new_table
Union 
Select id, name, address from old_table
Where id not in (select id from new_table)
```

Also, try not use id as column name. Very bad idea.